# Change the font color of outlook email by default

Tags: php, drupal-8

I am working on drupal 8 forms.Here, we have a button in the form section to trigger outlook mail with some template text.Is there any way to change the font style and font size of the content(body of mail)which is in the body of mail by default.

here is the code:

```
   $form['mail_body'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#title' => $this->t('Mail Body'),  
        '#default_value' => $template_message,
        '#attributes' => ['id' => ['mail_body_val']]
    );

    $form['overlay_link'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t('<a id="outlook_mail" class="send_mail1 button"        href="mailto:'.$user_email.'?subject= RE:Test">Send Mail</a>'),
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide code for outlook mail? Some css or preview ?

Comment: i just updated my question with code.Have a look

Comment: You can add in your default css style next code:
`#mail_body_val{
font-size://your font size
color://your font color
}`

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Are you try clear browser data first ?